# Rename the [ixl] tag to [is-x-legal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm always initially confused when I see the [ixl](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ixl) tag, because it's not a common initialism, and I only remember after hovering over it with my cursor (not an option for mobile users) that it stands for "Is X Legal?".

Can we rename the tag to the more immediately clear [is-x-legal](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/is-x-legal)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is an overhang from older days and should be updated as proposed to be more self-explanatory, yes.

Answer (score -1):

**This tag should be deleted**.
It does not [*characterize* the *topic* of a question](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).
I think most questions *implicitly* or *explicitly* ask “Is x legal?”
Thus tagging them as `ixl`/`is‑x‑legal` does not highlight a distinct feature.

Comment: This would perhaps be better addressed as a separate question, rather than an answer to this one.

Comment: Touche. I acknowledge that. I merely meant to provide a dissenting opinion. _Renaming_ is not the issue. I _definitely_ would appreciate if all tags were self-explanatory.

Comment: I disagree. I think that [tag:Is_x_legal]  does, in general, designate a certain type of question. many questions ask what the law requires in a given situation, or what legal procedures are,  or,whether a law is valid. Qs with this tag ask specifically whether a certain course of action violates law, often any law rather than a specified one.

I do agree that this should be a separate Meta question, where the issue can be discussed in detail, aside from the renaming (which has already been done).

Comment: "Is it legal to own a flamethrower?" is a rather simple question with a rather complicated story (yes, in many jurisdictions in fact, it is legal to own one) and fits into a very specific type of asking - which is usually a rather simple question with a complicated answer.

Comment: @Trish My argument is that the vast majority of questions on this site can be rephrased as “Is that legal?” I mean, if it is a question a court might discuss, it _is_ automatically a question of the “Is x legal” kind. Every court decision _does_ draw a line _between_ legality _and_ illegality. You know, _that_ is their job. Only questions about Why, When, Who and Where could not be phrased as “Is X legal?”, but such questions are quite rare on this site.